# ArangoDB Read timed out (read timeout=60)

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, arangodb, python-arango

I have a problem. I am using `ArangoDB enterprise:3.8.6` via `Docker`. But unfortunately my query takes longer than `30s`.
When it fails, the error is `arangodb HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8529): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)`.

- My collection is aroung 4GB huge and ~ 1.2 mio - 900k documents inside the collection.

How could I get the complete collection with all documents without any error?

Python code (runs locally on my machine)

```py
from arango import ArangoClient

# Initialize the ArangoDB client.
client = ArangoClient()

# Connect to database as  user.
db = client.db(<db>, username=<username>, password=<password>)

cursor = db.aql.execute(f'FOR doc IN students RETURN doc', batch_size=10000)
result = [doc for doc in cursor]

print(result[0])

[OUT]
arangodb HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8529): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
```

docker-compose.yml for ArangoDB

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  database:
    container_name: database__arangodb
    image: arangodb/enterprise:3.8.6
    environment:
      - ARANGO_LICENSE_KEY=<key>
      - ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - ARANGO_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=300
      - ARANGO_READ_TIMEOUT=600
    ports:
      - 8529:8529
    volumes:
      - C:/Users/dataset:/var/lib/arangodb3
```

What I tried

```py
cursor = db.aql.execute('FOR doc IN <Collection> RETURN doc', stream=True)
while cursor.has_more(): # Fetch until nothing is left on the server.
    cursor.fetch()
while not cursor.empty(): # Pop until nothing is left on the cursor.
    cursor.pop()

[OUT] CursorNextError: [HTTP 404][ERR 1600] cursor not found

# A N D 
cursor = db.aql.execute('FOR doc IN <Collection> RETURN doc', stream=True, ttl=3600)
collection =  [doc for doc in cursor]
[OUT] nothing # Runs, runs and runs for more than 1 1/2 hours
```

What worked **but** only for 100 documents

```py
# And that worked
cursor = db.aql.execute(f'FOR doc IN <Collection> LIMIT 100 RETURN doc', stream=True)
collection =  [doc for doc in cursor]
```

Comment: Is the Python code running in a container as well?

Comment: No, my Python Code is running locally on my machine

Comment: @Test has my answer answered your question or do you need any more clarification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can increase the HTTP client's [timeout](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts) by using a [custom HTTP client](https://docs.python-arango.com/en/main/http.html) for Arango.

The default is set [here](https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/python-arango/blob/ff990fde4a4403da170d8759adb46a7100e403a6/arango/http.py#L69) to 60 seconds.

```
from arango.http import HTTPClient


class MyCustomHTTPClient(HTTPClient):
    REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 1000 # Set the timeout you want in seconds here


# Pass an instance of your custom HTTP client to Arango:
client = ArangoClient(
    http_client=MyCustomHTTPClient()
)
```

Comment: your example raises because it treis to instantiate abstract class, this is an alternative I used:


`class MyCustomHTTPClient(DefaultHTTPClient):`